# How to get mksapiviewer to return unicode symbols in output

Tags: mks

I am using mksapiviewer to get information about different fields. Detailed Description field has Euro symbol. Because of that the api is not returning full strings and in xml it is not closing the  tag and missing the next open tag.

Command used to get xml for an issue:

```
mksAPIViewer --iplocal --xml im viewissue --showAttachments --showChangePackages --showHistory --showHistoryAscending --showRelationships
```

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Java api mksapi.jar is handling the special characters better than mksapiviewer executable though there are some issue with it.